# Accessing the Elements of a Reactive Object in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, closures, shiny

I'm having difficulty understanding how to access the elements of the closure returned by a call to `reactive(...)` in shiny R.

I have 3 `selectInput(...)` and some logic that allows for the selection of "All" in the drop-down - this is what feeds into (but is not shown) in the `_set()` closures at the top of `dfFiltered`.  Assume they work just fine with the reactive and a call to `renderPlot(...)`: they allow me to filter dates, and column contents like so:

```
dfFiltered <- eventReactive(input$summarize,{ 
  x <- x_set()
  y <- y_set()
  z <- z_set()

  start_numeric <- as.numeric(as.Date(isolate(input$date_range[1]), format = "%Y%m%d"));
  gt_start <- (data["updatedTimeYear"]*10000 +
    data["updatedTimeMonth"]*100 +
    data["updatedTimeDay"]) >= start_numeric;
  end_numeric <- as.numeric(as.Date(isolate(input$date_range[2]), format = "%Y%m%d"));
  lt_end <- (data["updatedTimeYear"]*10000 +
    data["updatedTimeMonth"]*100 +
    data["updatedTimeDay"]) <= end_numeric;
  out <- dplyr::filter(data,
    data$customer_env %in% envs &
    data$customer_name %in% custs &
    data$agent_name %in% sensors &
    data$updatedDate >= start_numeric & 
    data$updatedDate <= end_numeric
  );
  return(out);
})
```

Let's say for example I had a ggplot; again I know I can do something like this because I've been using this just fine in the current version of my shiny app:

```
output$opens_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = data.frame(dfFiltered())) +
      facet_grid(. ~ factor(direction), scales = 'free') +
      ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight(base_size = 14) +
      stat_summary(aes(x = updatedTimeHour, y = n_opens, fill = factor(direction)), 
                   color = 'black', 
                   alpha = 0.6,
                   fun.y = function(x) sum(x), 
                   geom = "bar") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) x/1000000) +
      labs(
        x = 'Hour of Day', 
        y = 'Opens (Millions)',
        title = 'Number of Opens, by Hour [Direction]')
      )
  })
```

However, when I turn to more complex plotting libraries like `hicharts` or `dygraphs` I find myself needing to access the columns of the closure directly.  (This isn't an issue in `gg` because I can just name the column.) My first attempts naively look something like this:

```
    hour <- dfFiltered()$updatedTimeHour
    flows <- dfFiltered()$n_flows

    output$flows_plot <- renderPlot({
    dygraph(day, flows, main = "N_Flows") %>% 
      dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c('2/20/2017','3/10/2017'))
      })

    # or...

      output$flows_plot <- renderPlot({
      highchart() %>%
        hc_title(text = "Scatter chart with size and color") %>%
        hc_add_series(data = dfFiltered(), type = 'scatter', dfFiltered()$updatedTimeHour, dfFiltered()$updatedTimeHour,
                                dfFiltered()$direction)
      })
```

I know there is probably an eas(ier) way to conceptualize this pipeline, from `reactive` -> `list` -> `data.frame` but I just can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: It should be treated the same as if it were a regular object, just cached for reduced computational time with the ability to update. ggplot() allows that sort of syntax whether the object is reactive or not - probably the same with the other plotting packages.  Or, perhaps, I'm not understanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

As Ryan Morton wrote, just treat it like a regular object (in this case a data.frame, which is assigned to local variable `df`):

```
output$flows_plot <- renderPlot({
  df <- dfFiltered()
  highchart() %>%
    hc_title(text = "Scatter chart with size and color") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = df, type = 'scatter', df$updatedTimeHour, df$updatedTimeHour, df$direction)
  })
```